# Изменения значений в столбце датафрейма в соответствии с условием

Tags: python, pandas, функции

Функция изменяет весь столбец датафрейма на одно и то же значение, игнорируя, что условия по строкам - разные. Или дает ошибку, если через `.apply`

Дайте, пожалуйста, совет на тему как правильно применить функцию через apply() в моей задаче, чтобы получить корректный результат.

Имеются 2 датафрейма Pandas с 'a','b','c' колонками. Я хочу изменить некоторые значения в 'c'-колонке для второго датафрейма df_2. Причем, нужно изменить данные в df_2 для 'c'-колонки только в тех строках, где 'a' равно 1. Значение 0 в ячейках этих строк в 'c'-колонках должны измениться на медиану, посчитанную от значений в 'c'-колонке первого датафрейма по строкам, где 'a' равно 1. Я написал функцию, которая делает это. Она применяется к df_2 и использует df_1.

**Проблема в следующем:**

1. Если применить функцию вот так: 'df_2['c'] = set_c(df_1, df_2)', то все 'c'-значения df_2 получают новую цену, и неважно, в данной строке 'a' == 1 или нет. Это неправильно.
2. Если применить функцию так: 'df_2['c'] = df_2.apply(set_c(df_2, df_1))', возникает ошибка без дополнительных комментариев: 'AssertionError:'.

**Код такой:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,1], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,100,9]}) # From C
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,50,6], 'c': [0,0,0]}) # To C

display('df_1', df_1)
display('df_2', df_2)

def set_c(df1, df2):
    
    mask = ( df1.loc[:, 'a'] == df2.loc[0, 'a'] )
    final_c = df1[mask]['c'].median()
    
    display("df2.loc[0, 'a']", df2.loc[0, 'a'])
    display('df1[mask]', df1[mask])
    print('final_c median', final_c)
    
    return final_c

df_2['c'] = set_c(df_1, df_2)

display(df_2)
```

В коде df_2 и df_1 - это глобальные датафреймы вне функции, а df2 and df1 - датафреймы внутри функции, передаваемые как параметры.

Моя функция показывает весь процесс расчетов. Для варианта 1 получается следующее:

```
'df_1'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   100
2   1   6   9

'df_2'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   0
1   2   50  0
2   3   6   0

"df2.loc[0, 'a']" # 'a'=1 - основа маски для 0 строки
1
 
'df1[mask]' # Строки df_1 с 'a'=1 найдены!
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
2   1   6   9

final_c median 8.0 # Медиана по 'c' для df1 между 7 и 9 = 8

'df_2 result'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   8.0
1   2   50  8.0
2   3   6   8.0
```

Могли бы вы показать мне, как правильно применить функцию через apply(), чтобы осуществились построчные расчеты и результирующий df_2 обрел бы такой вид, в котором новая ячейка колонки 'c' = 8.0 **была бы только в строке [0]**, так как только в строке [0] в df_2 есть 'a'=1, чтобы в строке [1] возникло 100 ('a'=2 есть в df_1, единственное число по 'c' = 100), и чтобы в строке [2] остался 0, так как 'a'=3 есть в df_2, но нет в df_1, поэтому медиану не считаем:

```
'df_2 result'
    a   b   c
0   1   4   8.0
1   2   50  100.0
2   3   6   0
```

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы сделал так:

сначала получаем соответствия между колонками `a` в обоих фреймах:

```
mapper = df_1.loc[df_2["a"].isin(df_1["a"])]["c"]
```

затем делаем замену во втором фрейме

```
df_2["c"] = df_2.apply(lambda x: mapper.loc[x.name]
                       if x.name in mapper.index else x["c"], axis=1)
```

а потом присваиваем вашу медиану по заданному условию:

```
df_2.loc[df_2["a"]==1, "c"] = df_1.loc[df_1["a"]==1, "c"].median()
```

получаем df_2:

```
   a   b    c
0  1   4    8
1  2  50  100
2  3   6    0
```

Comment: Уважаемый strawdog, большое Вам спасибо! Буду разбираться. )

Comment: Вообще, я бы советовал вам почитать про метод pandas под названием map. в более стандартных случаях он существенно облегчит вам решение задачи.

Comment: Благодарю, уважаемый strawdog! Мельком знакомился с ним, но постараюсь более пристально приглядеться. Я тут вообще узнал, что иногда удобными популярными средствами пользоваться не надо, так как в сравнении с ними неудобные средства повышают скорость работы до 600 раз. Статья где-то в сети есть. Это целый пласт, который копать надо.